# Docker Registry REST API authorization

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm trying to make requests to a private Docker registry but it requires me to login and responds with a 401 response. I've tried checking the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/registry_api/#authorization) but it doesn't say anything about the authorization process. So my questions is how to successfully make HTTP requests to a private Docker registry with authorization enabled using the REST API?

Comment: if memory serves me, since docker 0.9 the authentication uses TLS/SSL certificates. You need to set this up

Answer (score 1):

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04

That article was extremely helpful for me in setting up a secure private Docker registry. Goes through everything you'll need.

(This part, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04#step-four-—-secure-your-docker-registry-with-nginx, talks about securing the registry with basic HTTP authentication.)

Answer (score 0):

docker registry requires ssl to be set up; you will have to configure ssl to get it to work.

I tried following the tutorial on digitalocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-14-04)

But there are a number of little problems with it and I feel it doesn't quite do what I need it to.  I tried the ssl instructions verbatim and it didn't work for me.  Here is what I had to do to get set up with ssl (using fairly generic names) using a self-signed certificate:

Make a directory to store the ssl cert:

```
mkdir /etc/nginx/ssl
```

Create a certificate and key file:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt
```

Remember to put your common name as per instructions everywhere else (domain name)

Create a new directory under the ca-certificates directory:

```
mkdir /usr/share/ca-certificates/nginx
```

Copy the certificate file to that directory:

```
cp /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/
```

Append the following to the /etc/ca-certificates.conf file:

```
nginx/nginx.crt
```

Then update the certificates:

```
update-ca-certificates --fresh
```